# I cannot get puppeteer to click on radio buttons, no error is found the radio element or checkbox is just left unselected

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The item I am trying to click is a checkout radio on target Australia. In order to complete the checkout process you have to click on one of the boxes illustrated in the image below: [illustration of object I am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ7Ap.png) The error I am left with is that the box is left unticked therefore hindering my checkout process even though puppeteer is able to find the element.

Here is the code for the element:

`<label for="delivery-home-delivery" role="radio" aria-checked="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="select Home Delivery" class="DeliveryItem"><div class="CheckMark"></div><p class="Heading Heading--collapse Heading--h3 Heading--thin">Home Delivery</p><p class="Paragraph Paragraph--collapse Paragraph--tiny">$9 standard delivery.<br>Free for orders over $45</p></label> <input type="radio" class="u-visuallyHidden" id="delivery-home-delivery" name="delivery" tabindex="-1">`

Here is my JS code:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.target.com.au/p/optus-oppo-a53-mobile-phone/65110003', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });
  const [button] = await page.$$("#addToCartForm > div.prod-buttons-wrapper > div > div > button");
  let buttonclick = 1;
  while(buttonclick==1)
  {
  if (button) {
      console.log("element found");
      await page.click("#addToCartForm > div.prod-buttons-wrapper > div > div > button");
      break
  }
  
      await page.reload({waitUntil: ['networkidle0']});
      console.log("element not found");
      console.log(buttonclick);
      const [overlay] = await page.$x("/html/body/div[5]");
      if (overlay) { await page.mouse.click(10, 20, {button: 'left'});}
      try{
        await page.click("#addToCartForm > div.prod-buttons-wrapper > div > div > button");
        break;}
      finally{
        buttonclick = 2;}
}
  await page.goto("https://www.target.com.au/spc/order", {waitUntil: 'networkidle0',});
  
  const [emailbox] = await page.$x('//*[@id="CustomerEmailSearch.j_username"]');
  if(emailbox){

    await emailbox.type('gamingbradda01@gmail.com');
    console.log("emailbox found");
  }
  else{
      console.log("im sorry pupeteer cant see that");

  }
await page.click('#continue');
const homedeliv = await page.waitForSelector('#delivery-home-delivery');
if (homedeliv){console.log("we found home delivery item in checkout page");}
await page.click("#delivery-home-delivery");
const frame = await page.waitForSelector("body > div.CheckoutPage > div > div.Root > div > div.Page > div > div > section > span:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > section > div.DeliveryModeSelection.is-unselected > label:nth-child(3)");
//^This is one method I tested which finds the x and y coordinate of element than later clicks on it.
const rect = await page.evaluate(el => {
    const {x, y} = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {x, y};
  }, frame);
  console.log(rect.x);
  console.log(rect.y);
  await page.mouse.click(rect.x, rect.y, {button:'left', clickCount:2});
  console.log("click by element location found using puppet no work");
  await page.mouse.click(500, 450, {button:'left', clickCount: 2});
  await page.mouse.move(30, 20);


  
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to the attended result, keep in mind that waitForSelector uses a query selector to return an HtmlElement object. You need to use this object for the click method:

```
await page.click('#continue');
const homedeliv = await page.waitForSelector('#delivery-home-delivery');
if (homedeliv) {
    console.log("we found home delivery item in checkout page");
}
await homedeliv.click(); // Here you use homedeliv variable
```

Try to keep this logic for all your scrap code, I also suggest you to put some delay in your script, such as navigation delays or click delays to act like a human. Some website have anti-bots system that can ban your ip if it detects strange behaviour from your side.

**And for your rect method**, you should be able to use a query selector in order to double click the desired radio button, you generally don't want to move yourself your cursor.

You can always verify this with your browser inspector, some hints:

- Try to freeze your page so you can catch the html element you want
- Try to always use query selector or xpath